# Getting 404 error for font files with Azure hosted app - tried adding MIME type no luck

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm hosting an app on Azure. When accessing the app on a computer I get a 404 for all font files. I have checked the solution to add MIME types to web.config but with no change.

I have tried

> application/x-font-woff

as well as

> application/font-woff

but they yielded no useful results.

Path for the files in accurate. What else can be an issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it worked the second time around. Instead of copying and pasting font files or any other files for that matter, in visual studio it is always best to create the folder structure and import them as existing items

Answer (score 1):

Try removing any existing maps before adding your woff mimemap.

e.g:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
```

Comment: Did that as well. Not working. I get a 404 only for the font files; everything else runs spick and span

Comment: Hmm, okay - let's check the following then. Are the font files included into the solution? Do the font files have their build action set to "Content"? (if you're using continuous integration on Azure)

Comment: Yes. I have checked the font files are included in the solution, referenced appropriately in the css files and the build action is set to content with Don Not Copy. I tried changing to always copy; I am not sure how this affects Azure.I have no CI solution setup for Azure. ------------Thanks for the reply.

Comment: With a lot of trial and error finally solved the problem. I just created a new Font folder in my solution and moved all font files to it and changed references appropriately. Now all works find even on Azure.. I would still like to know what was causing it. However, no more urgency. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately I can only theorise as to why it worked for you that way, and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MIME types to the **W**eb.config not the **w**eb.config.

Like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" /> 
         </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```